# AJAX form and Rails render on js template?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I keep getting this missing template error that I dont know how to resolve. I have a remote link_to that creates a call to the new action and then renders the new.js.erb which contains a render to the html form. I want the ajax call to come in, route to the new.js.erb so that it can appened the regular new, including the form, into $('#form_account_contact'). I have attached directory structure as well.

new.js.erb

```
$('#form_account_contact').html('<%= escape_javascript render("new") %>');
```

Error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial tools/api_loaders/account_contact/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/tmedford/XXXX/XXXX/app/views"
  * "/Users/tmedford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/mercury-1cc637b0bcce/app/views"
  * "/Users/tmedford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise_security_extension-0.8.0/app/views"
  * "/Users/tmedford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.2.3/app/views"
):
    1: $('#form_account_contact').html('<%= escape_javascript render("new") %>');
  app/views/tools/api_loaders/account_contact/new.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_tools_api_loaders_account_contact_new_js_erb___3020976815342708085_70105536181780'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:94:in `set_time_zone'
```

[image: view directory]

[image: Controller Directory and new call]

Comment: you are missing partial called _new.html.erb that's why you are getting missing template error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update

```
$('#form_account_contact').html('<%= escape_javascript render("new") %>');
```

To

```
$('#form_account_contact').html('<%= escape_javascript render("form") %>');
```

In your `new.js.erb`, you are trying to render `form` partial. You passed incorrect name of the partial which is why you are getting error as there is no partial with the name `new`.